# Find independent of sequence uniform random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I have a question regarding the techniques of finding a uniform random variable that is independent of sequence of random variables.

**Context**: For some powerful statistical results (e.g., Theorem 5.1 of [E. Rio](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-54323-8)) it is necessary to prove that there exists such a random variable $U \sim Uniform([0, 1])$, that is independent of sequence of random variables $(\xi_i)_{I \in \mathbb{Z}}$.

**Question**: Suppose I have a sequence of random variables $(\xi_i)_{I \in \mathbb{Z}}$ on $\mathcal{X}$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$. What could be the general approach to prove that there is (is not) a uniform r.v. $U$ on $\mathcal{X}$ that is independent of $(\xi_i)_{I \in \mathbb{Z}}$?

**Comment**: Might there be any statements or techniques that could help with this? I am completely unaware how this kind of statements could be proved...

Comment: Such a $U$ always exists, possibly on an extension of the original probability space. Consider the original space $\Omega$ and define the extended space $\Omega\times [0,1]$, then you can choose the original measure times the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and $U$ to be the projection on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, thank you for the comment. The thing is that I cannot extend the probability space $\Omega$. I want to find a technique of proving if there is a r.v. $U$ defined on $\Omega$.

Comment: Then it depends on your choice of $\Omega$, not on the stochastic process. For example, if $\Omega$ consists of only a single point, evidently there will be no uniformly $[0,1]$ distributed random variable on it. Why do you care about the underlying probability space? Typically that is irrelevant for (most) probability questions.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, let me share the statement that I am curious about:


" Let $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be a sequence of random variables with values in some Polish space $X$. Assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{T}, \mathbb{P})$ is rich enough to contain a random variable $U$ with uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$, independent of $(\xi_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Let $\mathcal{F_0} = \sigma(\xi_i: i \le 0)$ and $\mathcal{G}_n = \sigma(\xi_i: i \ge n)$. Then one can construct a sequence..." Then there is implication of this condition. So I am wondering, when this theorem holds...

Comment: You should see this as a technical requirement only. In the end, we care about the random variables, not about the underlying space. You can extend whatever space you had in mind in the way I explained above, and then pretend that this was the original probability space you were working with. This does not change any properties of the stochastic process in question.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, thanks for the tip! Agree with what you said, makes sense, thank you!